# Content isn't properly loaded using jQuery's load() method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a series of pages who are wrapped in `<section id="content></section>` tags. When a link is clicked, I want to reload only that content section, not the header or footer. When I use this jQuery code, the content section is removed but never re-filled with the content from that new page:

```
$('.link').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = this.href;
    $('#content').remove();
    $('#content').load(url + ' #content').hide().fadeIn('fast'); 
});
```

This is a basic Ajax question, but I'm new to using Ajax and not sure where I went wrong here / if there's an easier solution to accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#content').remove();` destroys the `#content` element, so you're calling `load()` on an element that no longer exists, hence nothing happens.

To fix this change `remove()` to `empty()`:

```
$('#content').empty().load(url + ' #content *').hide().fadeIn('fast');
```

Also note that I amended the selector in `load()` to `#content *` otherwise you will end up duplicating the `#content` element, which would be less than ideal.